# Add Outlook shared folders to Evolution mail window

Tags: shared-folders, outlook-web-access, evolution

My company uses Outlook as mail server, and the only Linux client I managed to use without plugins or workarounds is Evolution.

My division implemented a shared folder, which I access in Outlook Webmail with my own credentials. I could find no way of adding this shared folder in Evolution. I tried:

- Add folder in a new account. Failed because the new account would have the same credentials, what was rejected by Evolution.
- Subscribe to the shared folder in my standard account settings. Failed because I have no idea on how to inform Evolution where the folder is.

My setup:

- Evolution 3.30.5-1.1
- Linux Mint Debian Edition 4

Could you pls help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your acct in the left panel -> Subscribe to folder of other user -> start typing the name of the shared inbox and select it -> Open.
Shows up in "Foreign Folders" under your accnt.

OR: in the Outlook webmail client - Outlook web app (OWA), right-click on your account in the left panel -> select "Add Shared folder" -> select the entry/accnt available -> Add.

Or (to be able to actually send mail from this shared acct, if you have permissions to do so): in OWA, click the icon in the upper-right corner -> "Open another mailbox" -> start typing the name of the shared inbox, select it -> Open.

Comment: Thanks! I have since moved to another team, which doesn't use shared mail folders, so I can't test it now. I shared your answer at work, in the hopes someone can.

Comment: @EmersonPrado, Great, sounds good. I realized just now that I didn't read your question carefully, where you mentioned that you already knew how to access via OWA. Anyway, hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to send as a shared mailbox directly from Evolution or is this only possible via OWA?